# How to use rowspan and colspan in tbody using datatable.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Whenever I use `<td colspan="x"></td>`, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined(…)

## Demo

```js
$("table").DataTable({});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:50%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td colspan="2">3 4</td>
      <td colspan="3">4 5 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's working properly without DataTables.js, but when we use this structure with datatable.js it is not working. We need above table structure. Does anyone have any idea how we can use this table structure datatable.js?

Comment: Right now, datatables do not support rowspan or colspan to the table body. [Reference](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/9510/do-datatables-support-rowspan-colspan-in-table-body) But, the possible solution should be [DataTables hidden row details example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html) Hope it works.

Comment: i have given the code, check the below url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088676/how-to-add-rowspan-in-jquery-datatables/40085706#40085706

Answer (score 110):

You can hack around the lack of colspan support by adding an "invisible" cell for every cell that's eliminated:

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="3">Wide column</td>
 <td style="display: none;"></td>
 <td style="display: none;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Normal column</td>
 <td>Normal column</td>
 <td>Normal column</td>
</tr>
```

DataTables doesn't complain, the table renders normally and sorting works (invisible columns sort as the empty string).

I haven't tried this with rowspan.

Comment: Note that if you have `scrollX` enabled, the cells get really misaligned with this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/3aprx7wk/4/

Comment: Tried this with `rowspan` also works but sorting could break the layout.

Comment: @Protocole Facing the same problem with sorting.. any work arounds?

Comment: Sorry, @BharatGeleda, I just don't need it and disabled it.

Comment: Very nice, thank you sir! I've added a <td class="d-none"></td> as I'm using bootstrap, and it works fine now.

Comment: well that's just brilliant! I wasted 3 hours trying to resolve and all I had to do to add invisible columns!!!

Answer (score 8):

#### COLSPAN: Ajax or JavaScript sourced data

Excellent solution provided by [Dirk Bergstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34012324/3549014) only works with HTML sourced data.

It is also possible to use the same idea with Ajax sourced data.

You need to use [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option to modify required cells when `TR` element is created in table body.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex){
        // If name is "Ashton Cox"
        if(data[0] === 'Ashton Cox'){
            // Add COLSPAN attribute
            $('td:eq(1)', row).attr('colspan', 3);

            // Hide required number of columns
            // next to the cell with COLSPAN attribute
            $('td:eq(2)', row).css('display', 'none');
            $('td:eq(3)', row).css('display', 'none');

            // Update cell data
            this.api().cell($('td:eq(1)', row)).data('N/A');
        }
    }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/oL229Lb5/) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: COLSPAN in table body TBODY - Ajax data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-colspan-in-table-body-tbody/#ajax-data) article for more details.

#### ROWSPAN

It is possible to emulate `ROWSPAN` attribute using [RowsGroup](https://github.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup) plug-in.

To use the plugin, you need to include JavaScript file `dataTables.rowsGroup.js` and use `rowsGroup` option to indicate indexes of the columns where you want grouping to be applied.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'rowsGroup': [2]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/pen9wnj8/) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: ROWSPAN in table body TBODY](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-rowspan-in-table-body-tbody/) article for more details.

#### COLSPAN and ROWSPAN

It is possible to group cells both vertically and horizontally simultaneously if we combine both workarounds described above.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/efuwgg1L/) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: COLSPAN in table body TBODY - COLSPAN and ROWSPAN](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-colspan-in-table-body-tbody/#colspan-and-rowspan) article for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `scrollX`

```
<thead>
<tr>
 <th style="width: 20px;"></th>
 <th>column H</td>
 <th>column H</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td colspan="3">Wide column</td>
 <td style="display: none;"></td>
 <td style="display: none;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>123</td>
 <td>Normal column</td>
 <td>Normal column</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Modified answer of #Dirk_Bergstrom

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link.

[fnFakeRowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971461/jquery-plugin-datatable-using-rowspan-in-tbody-causes-wrong)

Also refer the plugin here.

[fnFakeRowspan plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnFakeRowspan#)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know at what point, but I guess the fnFakeRowspan does not support the current DataTable version.

For an alternative, checkout [RowsGroup](https://github.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup) plugin.

Found it pretty easy to implement and works well. 
Searching works perfectly, ordering doesn't.

Check [here](http://live.datatables.net/bodanole/1/edit) for an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Because datatables doesn't support `colspan`, I usually ended up with using unordered lists (`ul`) with `list-style: none;`

[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA2rG.png)