# TypeError: aLayout[(i + k)] is undefined datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am getting `TypeError: aLayout[(i + k)] is undefined` 
in console when specifying any `rowspan` or `columnspan` value. It is working fine without this, but I need to have these things as I need to group certain columns. I am using zero config datatables and code is given below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#points_table").DataTable();
});
```

and the error is showing on this line in datatable JS :

TypeError: aLayout[(i + k)] is undefined

"unique": bUnique

My datatable version is `1.9.4`

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290693/how-to-use-rowspan-and-colspan-in-tbody-using-datatable-js-in-codeigniter

Comment: I need something like this only. But even after giving the configuration, it is showing error https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html

Comment: How does the markup looks like?

Comment: Console is showing error on this line 

...e++)for(g=0;g<m;g++)a[f+g][o+e]={cell:i,unique:p},a[f+g].nTr=d}i=i.nextSibling}}...