# How to add Rowspan in JQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html-table

Im using Jquery datatables to construct a table.
My requirement is like below
[image]

This is not a static table, and we are rendering it using json data. 
Here I'm, rendering the rows dynamically using "aoColumns".
Is there any way to use **rowspan** so that the cells (1,2,David,Alex) can be spanned.

Does datatables support this kind of table ?

Comment: It doesn't support rowspan in table body.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Datatables does not support this kind of grouping out of the box.
But, as in many cases, there is a plugin available.

It is called RowsGroup and is located here: [Datatables Forums](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29319/new-rowsgroup-plugin-merge-cells-vertically-rowspan). A [live example](http://live.datatables.net/bodanole/1/edit) is also included.

If you change the JS part in this example to the below you will have your desired output presented to you in the output window.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var data = [
    ['1', 'David', 'Maths', '80'],
    ['1', 'David', 'Physics', '90'],
    ['1', 'David', 'Computers', '70'],
    ['2', 'Alex', 'Maths', '80'],
    ['2', 'Alex', 'Physics', '70'],
    ['2', 'Alex', 'Computers', '90'],
  ];
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [
        {
            name: 'first',
            title: 'ID',
        },
        {
            name: 'second',
            title: 'Name',
        },
        {
            title: 'Subject',
        }, 
        {
            title: 'Marks',
        },
    ],
    data: data,
    rowsGroup: [
      'first:name',
      'second:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
    });
} );
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: I have used this. The `rowspan` works but the pagination breaks. Any idea of how to get this fixed?

Comment: Yes, the pagination is not working in my case as well. whenever I click on second page, it does nothing and be on first page itself. any idea?

Comment: mine doesnt work, any idea why? https://pastebin.com/hs4GRxjS
i am using datatables 1.13.3 and rowgroup 1.2.0

Answer (score 11):

I tried the [RowsGroup plugin](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-colspan-in-table-body-tbody/), but it achieves this just by hijacking the DataTables sort mechanism.  If you tell it to group a given column, what it does for you is basically to apply a sort to that column that you can't turn off.  So, if you want to sort by another column, you can't.  That didn't work in my application.

Instead, here's a working fiddle for a recipe that allows you to achieve this result:

https://jsfiddle.net/bwDialogs/fscaos2n

The basic idea is to flatten all of your multi-row data into a single row.  Content in your 2nd, 3rd, etc. rows are stored as a hidden `<script>` template tag within your first row.

It works by using DataTables' `drawCallback` function to manipulate the DOM once DataTables has rendered it, without confusing DataTables by having to try parsing `rowspan` cell content.

Since this modifies the DOM after DataTables has done its magic, your multi-row sections will stick together even with pagination, searching, and sorting.

Cheers.

---

**EDIT:** Here's another fiddle with an additional convenience method to convert most HTML-based tables into what the `drawCallback` function expects: https://jsfiddle.net/zuxLq4g8/

It checks for all rows without rowspans, and inserts them into template scripts in the rows above with rowspans. If you have some rows that are completely on their own, this code won't work.

Comment: Thanks, it work like charm.... this is what i need since one of my column need to be groupped but it has the same "html" content for each row which cant be applied using RowGroup Extension or i just cant use it haha :( Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Awesome stuff. Yet to find a better answer than this one. Thanks!

Answer (score -6):

add a below code and modify according to your requirement

```
$(window).on("load",function() {           
            MakeRows();
            addRowspan();
            $(".paginate_button").on("click", function() {
                MakeRows();
                addRowspan();
            });
        });

        function MakeRows() {
            var tmp_tbl = $("#dashboardDetails");
            var _l = tmp_tbl.find("tr");
            var _td = "",_t_td = "", old_txt = "",_t_txt = ""; _tr_count = 1;_tr_countadd = 1;
            for(i = 0;i< _l.length; i ++) {
                _t_td = tmp_tbl.find("tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(0).find("span");
                _t_txt = $(_t_td).text();
                _t_txt = _t_txt.replace(/\//,"_");_t_txt = _t_txt.replace(/\//,"_");

                if (_t_txt.length > 0) {
                    if(_t_txt != old_txt) {
                        if($(_l).eq(i).hasClass(_t_txt) == false) {
                            _tr_count = 1;_tr_countadd = 1;
                            $(_l).eq(i).addClass("" + _t_txt + "").addClass(_t_txt + "_" + i);
                        }
                        old_txt = _t_txt;
                    } else {
                        _tr_count = _tr_count + 1;
                        if (_tr_countadd == 1) {
                            $(_l).eq(i).addClass("" + _t_txt + "").addClass(_t_txt + "_" + i)
                                .addClass("hiddenClass").addClass("maintr").attr("trcount", _tr_count).attr("addedtrcount", "maintr");                            
                            _tr_countadd = _tr_countadd + 1;
                        } else {
                            $(_l).eq(i).addClass("" + _t_txt + "").addClass(_t_txt + "_" + i)
                                .addClass("hiddenClass").attr("trcount", _tr_count)
                        }
                    }
                }
                _t_td = "";
            }
        }

        function addRowspan() {
            var t_txt = "";
            var _alltrmain = $(".maintr");
            var _h_td = ["0","10","11","12","13"];
            for (i = 0; i <= _alltrmain.length; i ++) {
                for (j = 0; j <= _h_td.length; j ++) {
                    t_txt = $(_alltrmain).eq(i).attr("trcount");
                    $(_alltrmain).eq(i).prev().find("td").eq(_h_td[j]).attr("rowspan", t_txt);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could at least (1) explain what and how the code works and (2) refactor it to make it readable. It's not easy to "modify" code like that.

Comment: modify? are you joking?

Comment: I only see a random text that looks like code sometimes :S

Comment: It looks like if JavaScript had a stroke