# Create table with row and column spans using JQuery datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there a way I can create a table using Jquery Datatable which supports both row and column spans.
I will have a JSON object to pass to the table.
The object will have some single items and some subarrays.
The single items needs to be rowspanned for the multiple items subarrays.

I'll have my object as :

```
var myArr = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": 'Ken',
    "Age": '30',
    "Hobbies": [{
      'HobbyId': 1,
      'HobbyName': 'Swimming'
    }, {
      'HobbyId': 2,
      'HobbyName': 'Reading'
    }],
    "Skills": [{
      'SkillId': 1,
      'SkillName': 'PHP'
    }, {
      'SkillId': 2,
      'SkillName': 'MySQL'
    }],
    "Language": [{
      'LangId': 2,
      'LangName': 'English'
    }, {
      'LangId': 3,
      'LangName': 'Chinese'
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": 'Mike',
    "Age": '20',
    "Hobbies": [],
    "Skills": [],
    "Language": []
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": 'Charlie',
    "Age": '25',
    "Hobbies": [{
      'HobbyId': 5,
      'HobbyName': 'Dance'
    }, {
      'HobbyId': 6,
      'HobbyName': 'Sing'
    }, {
      'HobbyId': 7,
      'HobbyName': 'Writing'
    }],
    "Skills": [],
    "Language": [{
      'Id': 7,
      'Name': 'English'
    }]
  }
]
```

My table should then look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W40Oq.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Rowspan in JQuery datatables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088676/how-to-add-rowspan-in-jquery-datatables)

Comment: please check this link that help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088676/how-to-add-rowspan-in-jquery-datatables

Comment: @AshishKadam Thanks but the way there array is being used is different from mine.I am having subarray concept and I don't want to mess up with that.