# Datatable failing with rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using [*jQuery DataTables*](https://datatables.net/) to render my grid data and am using the concept of rowspan with rowsGroup option.
Its spanning some rows and look good but after some rows its failing.

I followed these examples:

- http://live.datatables.net/bodanole/1/edit
- [How to add Rowspan in JQuery datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088676)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resultArray = [
    ["290013", "TEST OF ENSEMBLE", "11-25-2016", "", "", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "2002", "XXX5", "XXX5", "XXX5", "", "1864", "2017", "VERSION", "23004746", "XXX5", "", "One Time", "", "", "", "", "", "", "21004482", "9189", "Feature Set", "20003880", "XXX5", "XXX5", "BASE", "19-APR-2017", "04-18-2017", "3877", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "1865", "Deluxe", "EDITION", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9190", "Charge", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  ];

  console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [{
      title: 'Item Master Number',
      name: 'ItemMasterNumber'
    }, {
      title: 'Description',
      name: 'Description'
    }, {
      title: 'First Processing Date',
      name: 'FirstProcessingDate'
    }, {
      title: 'Alias',
      name: 'Alias'
    }, {
      title: 'Master Price',
      name: 'MasterPrice'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Id',
      name: 'ProductId'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Description',
      name: 'ProductDescription'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set#',
      name: 'FeatureSetId'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Code',
      name: 'FeatureSetCode'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Name',
      name: 'FeatureSetName'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Description',
      name: 'Feature Set Description'
    }, {
      title: 'Enablement Type',
      name: 'Enablement Type'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Id',
      name: 'FeatureId'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Name',
      name: 'AttributeName'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Value',
      name: 'AttributeValue'
    }],
    data: resultArray,
    rowsGroup: [
      // Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified
      // order to which rows groupping is applied.
      // (column-selector could be any of specified in:
      // https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)
      'ItemMasterNumber:name', 'Description:name', 'FirstProcessingDate:name', 'Alias:name', 'MasterPrice:name',
      'ProductId:name',
      'ProductDescription:name',
      'FeatureSetId:name',
      'FeatureSetCode:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.container {
  min-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/** Hide console */
.as-console-wrapper { display: none !important; }
```

```html
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.mcfcloud.com/jquery-1.11.2/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup/v1.0.0/dataTables.rowsGroup.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
  </table>
</div>
```

It spans till the *Product Description* column and then fails to span.
I want it to span *Feature ID*, *Feature Code* and lot of other columns.

Comment: You have pasted twice your code.

Comment: @RohanKumar Thanks,updated the code now.

Comment: @Hemant Thanks, I have made it shorter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**How to use rowspan and colspan in tbody using datatable.js?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290693/how-to-use-rowspan-and-colspan-in-tbody-using-datatable-js)

Comment: @chsdk Can you please explain me how is this a possible duplicate?

Comment: If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088676/how-to-add-rowspan-in-jquery-datatables you can see that datatables doesn't support rowspan and colspan, and you haven't included angular in your question, so how will you use **RowsGroup** plugin?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables can apply rowspan only on unique values for each row, if any rowspan column has differnt value then it will not work, see below snippet in which I have applied rowspan on Item Number and Description, and last 2 rows have common values(`290015` and `XXX5`) so rowspan work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resultArray = [
    ["290013", "TEST OF ENSEMBLE", "11-25-2016", "", "", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "F1 id", "F1 code", "F1 name", "F1 desc", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "2002", "XXX5 id", "XXX5", "XXX name", "", "1864", "2017", "VERSION", "23004746", "XXX5", "", "One Time", "", "", "", "", "", "", "21004482", "9189", "Feature Set", "20003880", "XXX5", "XXX5", "BASE", "19-APR-2017", "04-18-2017", "3877", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "CC 1", "Code2", "Name", "Desc", "", "1865", "Deluxe", "EDITION", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9190", "Charge", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  ];

  console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [{
      title: 'Item Master Number',
      name: 'ItemMasterNumber'
    }, {
      title: 'Description',
      name: 'Description'
    }, {
      title: 'First Processing Date',
      name: 'FirstProcessingDate'
    }, {
      title: 'Alias',
      name: 'Alias'
    }, {
      title: 'Master Price',
      name: 'MasterPrice'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Id',
      name: 'ProductId'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Description',
      name: 'ProductDescription'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set#',
      name: 'FeatureSetId'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Code',
      name: 'FeatureSetCode'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Name',
      name: 'FeatureSetName'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Description',
      name: 'Feature Set Description'
    }, {
      title: 'Enablement Type',
      name: 'Enablement Type'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Id',
      name: 'FeatureId'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Name',
      name: 'AttributeName'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Value',
      name: 'AttributeValue'
    }],
    data: resultArray,
    rowsGroup: [
      // Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified
      // order to which rows groupping is applied.
      // (column-selector could be any of specified in:
      // https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)
      'ItemMasterNumber:name',
      'Description:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.container {
  min-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/** Hide console */
.as-console-wrapper { display: none !important; }
```

```html
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.mcfcloud.com/jquery-1.11.2/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup/v1.0.0/dataTables.rowsGroup.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks I understood and its working, though I wanted to know how can we implement colspan so that all the Feature Set columns falls under one header named "Feature Set"

Comment: Also, I cant sort the columns.I can sort the first and columns under Features but not others.

Comment: In my snippet I found that sorting will not work when using `rowsGroup`. Also, it is working when I am not using `rowsGroup`.

Comment: But it works here http://live.datatables.net/bodanole/1/edit, not sure why is that so.

Comment: The third group is not working in the your given URL.