# Datatables not sorting some of the columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables to render data to my table, along with rowsGroup plugin for rowspan.
But I am able to sort only some of the columns and not all.
Below is my code, its sorting the first column and not the rest ones.
Why is that so and how can I resolve this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resultArray = [
    ["290013", "TEST OF ENSEMBLE", "11-25-2016", "", "", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "2002", "XXX5", "XXX5", "XXX5", "", "1864", "2017", "VERSION", "23004746", "XXX5", "", "One Time", "", "", "", "", "", "", "21004482", "9189", "Feature Set", "20003880", "XXX5", "XXX5", "BASE", "19-APR-2017", "04-18-2017", "3877", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "1865", "Deluxe", "EDITION", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9190", "Charge", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  ];

  console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [{
      title: 'Item Master Number',
      name: 'ItemMasterNumber'
    }, {
      title: 'Description',
      name: 'Description'
    }, {
      title: 'First Processing Date',
      name: 'FirstProcessingDate'
    }, {
      title: 'Alias',
      name: 'Alias'
    }, {
      title: 'Master Price',
      name: 'MasterPrice'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Id',
      name: 'ProductId'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Description',
      name: 'ProductDescription'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set#',
      name: 'FeatureSetId'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Code',
      name: 'FeatureSetCode'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Name',
      name: 'FeatureSetName'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Description',
      name: 'Feature Set Description'
    }, {
      title: 'Enablement Type',
      name: 'Enablement Type'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Id',
      name: 'FeatureId'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Name',
      name: 'AttributeName'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Value',
      name: 'AttributeValue'
    }],
    data: resultArray,
    rowsGroup: [
      // Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified
      // order to which rows groupping is applied.
      // (column-selector could be any of specified in:
      // https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)
      'ItemMasterNumber:name',
      'Description:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
  });
});
```

Code snippet : [Datatable failing with rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678592/datatable-failing-with-rowspan/43679566#43679566)

Comment: Could you please reproduce the problem either in `jsfiddle` or in `stack snippet`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I am not sure on how to do that but I have added a link to snippet which is my actual example and the question was asked earlier by me and the code snippet was added by some editor.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me out with this?

Comment: Couldn't get much help with that but I assume **[this is what you are trying](http://live.datatables.net/bodanole/1/edit)**!! and here's the **[discussion forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29319/new-rowsgroup-plugin-merge-cells-vertically-rowspan)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Did you tried the link of the snippet I shared in my question. If you see there am not able to sort 2nd,3rd and more columns.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes, I did follow the example you mentioned.