# Jquery Datatable displaying incorrect count and pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables to display my table and using rowsGroup plugin to implement rowspan on it.
I have followed [How to add Rowspan in JQuery datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088676/how-to-add-rowspan-in-jquery-datatables) to add rowspan.
Rowspan stuff works good but the issue is I now see incorrect count.
Even if you see in the link above it is saying wrong in the screenshot.
Also, the pagination ends up incorrectly.
Is there any way we can achieve the correct output on count and pagination?

Below is my code sample. An using rowsGroup plugin for rowspan and so it displays 2 records instead of 3 on the table.
But in count it displays incorrectly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resultArray = [
    ["290013", "TEST OF ENSEMBLE", "11-25-2016", "", "", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "2002", "XXX5", "XXX5", "XXX5", "", "1864", "2017", "VERSION", "23004746", "XXX5", "", "One Time", "", "", "", "", "", "", "21004482", "9189", "Feature Set", "20003880", "XXX5", "XXX5", "BASE", "19-APR-2017", "04-18-2017", "3877", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "1865", "Deluxe", "EDITION", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9190", "Charge", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  ];
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [{
      title: 'Item Master Number',
      name: 'ItemMasterNumber'
    }, {
      title: 'Description',
      name: 'Description'
    }, {
      title: 'First Processing Date',
      name: 'FirstProcessingDate'
    }, {
      title: 'Alias',
      name: 'Alias'
    }, {
      title: 'Master Price',
      name: 'MasterPrice'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Id',
      name: 'ProductId'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Description',
      name: 'ProductDescription'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set#',
      name: 'FeatureSetId'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Code',
      name: 'FeatureSetCode'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Name',
      name: 'FeatureSetName'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Description',
      name: 'Feature Set Description'
    }, {
      title: 'Enablement Type',
      name: 'Enablement Type'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Id',
      name: 'FeatureId'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Name',
      name: 'AttributeName'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Value',
      name: 'AttributeValue'
    }],
    data: resultArray,
    rowsGroup: [
      // Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified
      // order to which rows groupping is applied.
      // (column-selector could be any of specified in:
      // https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)
      'ItemMasterNumber:name',
      'Description:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
  });
});
```

Below is the screenshot of the issue.
[image: Screenshot]
Here you can see there are only 2 visible entries and still the count displays 3.

Comment: Can you please share your code for review?

Comment: @KhanjanBhatt added my code.The issue is there too in the other stackoverflow link I shared in my question.

Comment: Sonali can you please give screenshot of your output.

Comment: Scroll right.... the message at the bottom is a count of rows, not of row groups.  If you scroll right you should see the row group for Item 290015 contains two rows.