# How to use Rowspan in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using Spring Boot and MySQL. I have data in following structure.

[image]

I try to show it like following structure. I'm using datatable [Datatable link](https://datatables.net/), I tried using api(s) of datatable and javascript in many ways to do, but I couldn't make it.

Few links describe to be done with `$('#datatable').DataTable({'rowsGroup': [0]})`, but not working. I implemented using map in Java. But I feel better if I do it in front-end

[image]

- Datetime always unique and each Datetime has 6 records always
- Value should be `sum(value)/(distinct Datetime)`
- If null/empty values are passing in feedback, *ignore title and    feedback only*

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Rowspan in JQuery datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088676/how-to-add-rowspan-in-jquery-datatables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use datatable rowsGroup plugin. See the link -
[datatables-rowsgroup](https://github.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup) or [New RowsGroup plugin](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29319/new-rowsgroup-plugin-merge-cells-vertically-rowspan)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var data = [
    ['1', 'David', 'Maths', '80'],
    ['1', 'David', 'Physics', '90'],
    ['1', 'David', 'Computers', '70'],
    ['2', 'Alex', 'Maths', '80'],
    ['2', 'Alex', 'Physics', '70'],
    ['2', 'Alex', 'Computers', '90'],
  ];
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [
        {
            name: 'first',
            title: 'ID',
        },
        {
            name: 'second',
            title: 'Name',
        },
        {
            title: 'Subject',
        }, 
        {
            title: 'Marks',
        },
    ],
    data: data,
    rowsGroup: [
      'first:name',
      'second:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
    });
} );
```

[Click here](http://live.datatables.net/bodanole/5897/edit) to view the example.

Comment: if no of columns dynamic than how to implement row span in whole grid.. what we need to pass in rowsGroup..