# DataTables not work when i use rolspan in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatable

i want to show  multiple products across a date

links to use

I use Rospans in table as give below

but when i not use rospans datatables show correctly

CSS

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

JS or JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

my tab

```
<table class="table table-bordered display" id="Table" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Plant Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Cement Pack</th>
            <th scope="col">No.of Pallets</th>
            <th scope="col">Tiles / Pallet</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Tiles in SFT</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead class="table table-dark">
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($stocks as $index => $stock)
            @php
                $count = $stock->products->count();
            @endphp
            <tr>
                    <td rowspan="{{ $count }}" class="align-middle rowspan-cell">
                        {{ $stock->date }}
                    </td>
                <td>{{ $stock->products?->first()?->plant_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stock->products?->first()?->mainProduct->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stock->products?->first()?->mainSize->size }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stock->products?->first()?->cement_packs }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stock->products?->first()?->no_pallets }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stock->products?->first()?->tiles_pallets }}</td>
                <td>{{ $stock->products?->first()?->total_tiles_sft }}</td>
                    <td rowspan="{{ $count }}" class="align-middle rowspan-cell">
                        <!-- edit -->
                        <a class="btn  btn-sm btn-parrot-green text-white" href=""><i
                                class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        <!-- delete -->
                        @php
                            $modelId = 'modelDelete' . $stock->id;
                        @endphp
                        @component('components.delete-model', ['modelId' => $modelId, 'Action' => route('tuffTile.destroy', $stock->id)])
                        @endcomponent
                    </td>
            </tr>
            @if ($count > 1)
                @foreach ($stock->products->slice(1) as $product)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $product->plant_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $product->mainProduct->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $product->mainSize->size }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $product->cement_packs }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $product->no_pallets }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $product->tiles_pallets }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $product->total_tiles_sft }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

js code:

```
$('#Table').DataTable({});
```

i want to try to show dataTables when i use rospan but show error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')

But when i not use rospan then it show correctly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32088676/1427878 recommends using the RowsGroup plugin.