# Bootstrap datatable search pagination disappears while used rowspan

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination, html-table

I'm using CodeIgniter v2 and Bootstrap v2.3.2. Well, my datatable has the class `example2` for bootstrap pagination, here it is:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="example2">
```

Search and pagination magically disappears only when I add rowspan to the table. I added rowspan to be dynamic, just like this:

```
echo '<td rowspan="'. $rowspan[$row['increment_id']].'">' . $row['increment_id'] . '</td>';`
```

Is it causing the issue?

Comment: My issue is different! I can use bootstrap search and pagination normally. It works fine if I do not have any rowspan. Disappears only when I use rowspan to the table!! @Abdulla

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the cause of my problem. Yes, its because I used `rowspan` inside `tbody`. Datatable doesn't support `rowspan or colspan` inside `tbody`
Here is the question from stackexchange that helped me finding the cause: [How to use rowspan and colspan in tbody using datatable.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290693/how-to-use-rowspan-and-colspan-in-tbody-using-datatable-js-in-codeigniter)