# colspan not working in datatables?

Tags: php, html

i have a table and i'm using datatables and its working without any colspan added to it..but when i try to add a colspan on the last column the filtering, searching and pagination are all not showing..how can i supposed to work it out.please help me..

**here is my code**

**CSS**

```
.table_wrapper{
    margin-top:5px;
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
    border: 3px dashed red;
    height:600px;

}
.datatables{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
}
thead th{
    background-color:#6a782a;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

tbody td{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table_wrapper">
    <table class="datatables table-striped" width="100%">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>LHID</th>
                <th>LO Name</th>
                <th>Province</th>
                <th>Municipality</th>
                <th>Barangay</th>
                <th>Title Number</th>
                <th>Lot Number</th>
                <th>Survey Number</th>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>RLBET Action</th>
                <th>Reasons</th>
                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <?php
                    //$query = "SELECT * FROM login";
                    echo $LTID->viewdetails();

                 ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Must be working! I'm use it!

Comment: its not working on me..the search,pagination and the fsolrting are all not showing

Comment: without colspan its working but with colspan added its not working

Comment: Hmm... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290693/how-to-use-rowspan-and-colspan-in-tbody-using-datatable-js-in-codeigniter/34012324#34012324

Comment: @Deep i have tried tried already but i think i just do it in the wrong way..can you help me fic it.please..

Comment: DataTables version? Here example for 1.10.12: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Comment: the version of my datatable is v1.10.12