# JQuery DataTable not working the table is not a foundation table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create table with DataTable library (that using foundation-zurb), This is the table html code:

```
 <table dir="rtl" id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%; ">
  <thead style="margin-top:0%;">
    <tr class="top-table">
      <th>
        <label class="tableHeaders">
          <fmt:message key="subjectName" />
        </label>
      </th>
      <th>
        <label class="tableHeaders">
          <fmt:message key="subSubjectName" />
        </label>
      </th>
      <th>
        <label style="float:right;">
          <fmt:message key="department" />
        </label>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${sub_subjects}" var="subject" varStatus="status">
      <th rowspan="${subject.length}">
        <form:hidden path="" name="sub_subjects[${status.index}].description" id="sub_subjects[${status.index}].id" value="${subject.description}" />${subject.description}</th>
      <c:forEach items="${subject.subSubjectsList}" var="subsubject" varStatus="statusSub">
        <tr>
          <!--  <td ><form:hidden path="" name="sub_subjects_list[${status.index}].subjectObj.view" id="sub_subjects_list[${status.index}].subjectObj.view" value="${subsubject.subjectObj.view}"/>${subsubject.subjectObj.view}</td>-->
          <td>
            <form:hidden path="" name="subSubjectsList[${statusSub.index}].description" id="subSubjectsList[${statusSub.index}].description" value="${subsubject.description}" />${subsubject.description}</td>
          <td>
            <form:hidden path="" name="subSubjectsList[${statusSub.index}].departmentObj.inCurrentLanguage" id="subSubjectsList[${statusSub.index}].departmentObj.inCurrentLanguage" value="${subsubject.departmentObj.inCurrentLanguage}" />${subsubject.departmentObj.inCurrentLanguage}</td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

also I added this scripts to my html file:

```
<script src="r/lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="r/lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="r/lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/Responsive-2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>


$(document).foundation();
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "url": "resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/hebrew.json"
    },
    "columnDefs": [{ // "targets": [], // "orderable": false }, { responsivePriority:
      1,
      targets: 0
    }, {
      responsivePriority: 2,
      targets: 1
    }, ],
    responsive: false,
  });
  $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
    dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
  });
  $("#searchbox").on("keyup search input paste cut", function() {
    dataTable.search(this.value).draw();
  });
});

</script>
```

Here are the links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/css/foundation.css">


<link href="resources/cssf/addCss.css?version=6" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/media/css/dataTables.foundation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/Responsive-2.1.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
<link href="r/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My problem is that the DataTable not working, I get error on this line in js file:

```
i._DT_CellIndex = {
  row: b,
  column: l
};
g.push(i);
if ((!c || n.mRender || n.mData !== l) && (!h.isPlainObject(n.mData) || n.mData._ !== l + ".display")) i.innerHTML = B(a, b, l, "display");
n.sClass && (i.className += " " + n.sClass);
n.bVisible && !c ? j.appendChild(i) : !n.bVisible && c && i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
```

I also using DataTable in another pages and its working fine, only on this page I got this error. Someone have any idea about my problem?

This is the table that I want to get:

```
*****************************
subject * sub-subject * dep *
*****************************
sub_1   * sub sub1    * 1   *
        *********************
        * sub sub2    * 2   *
*****************************
sub_2   * sub sub 4   * 1   *
*****************************
sub_3   * sub sub 3   * 1   *
        *********************
        * sub sub 5   * 2   *
        *********************
        * sub sub 6   * 2   *
*****************************
```

Comment: This error offten occurs when the number of columns indicated by your data does not match the number of columns present in the header row of your table's html. I'd start there

Comment: it looks like you're opening <tr> is in the wrong place.  It's below your first column, and should be right  after the start of your for loop.

Comment: yes I know, I added image of the table that I want to get,  if you have any idea how to resolve this issue write it to me.

Comment: @foo Looks like you are trying to create a table which requires `rowspan` or `colspan`, which might be why your columns don't match up properly. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290693/how-to-use-rowspan-and-colspan-in-tbody-using-datatable-js-in-codeigniter

Comment: yes, I do this table but there is no way to combine this two things together?