# Datatables Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to dynamically create a Datatable within an ajax call. Datatables always throws the following exception:

`Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined`

This is the responsible codesnippet:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(forms, null, 2)},
        async: true,
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.code === 1){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.mode === 'table'){
                    el = document.getElementById('fetcher');
                    table = document.createElement('table');
                    table.setAttribute('id', 'fetcherTable');
                    el.appendChild(table);
                    $('#fetcherTable').DataTable({
                        data: data.data.data,
                        columns: data.data.columns,
                        paging: false,
                        searching: false
                    })
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (request, error, errortext) {
            console.log("error: " + error);
            console.log(request);
        }
    });
```

The received data has the following form:

```
{
   "code":1,
   "data":{
      "colums":[
         {
            "data":"id",
            "title":"ID"
         },
         {
            "data":"pid",
            "title":"PID"
         },
         {
            "data":"title",
            "title":"Titel"
         },
         {
            "data":"stand",
            "title":"Stand"
         },
         {
            "data":"filename",
            "title":"Dateiname"
         },
         {
            "data":"fileformat",
            "title":"Dateiformat"
         },
         {
            "data":"processed",
            "title":"Prozessiert"
         },
         {
            "data":"valid",
            "title":"Valide"
         },
         {
            "data":"readable",
            "title":"Lesbar"
         },
         {
            "data":"fetchid",
            "title":"FetcherID"
         }
      ],
      "data":[
         {
            "id":69,
            "pid":"None",
            "title":"None",
            "stand":"2020-08-04T12:27:39.209133+02:00",
            "filename":"20200804122905_None",
            "fileformat":"xlb",
            "processed":"2020-08-04T12:27:39.551378+02:00",
            "valid":"2020-08-04T12:27:39.212346+02:00",
            "readable":"2020-08-04T12:27:39.263416+02:00",
            "fetchid":740
         },
         {
            "id":68,
            "pid":"None",
            "title":"None",
            "stand":"2020-08-04T11:12:22.030491+02:00",
            "filename":"20200804111347_None",
            "fileformat":"xlb",
            "processed":"2020-08-04T11:12:22.436609+02:00",
            "valid":"2020-08-04T11:12:22.036467+02:00",
            "readable":"2020-08-04T11:12:22.088224+02:00",
            "fetchid":740
         },
         {
            "id":67,
            "pid":"None",
            "title":"None",
            "stand":"2020-08-04T11:11:52.807305+02:00",
            "filename":"20200804111318_None",
            "fileformat":"xlb",
            "processed":"2020-08-04T11:11:53.373856+02:00",
            "valid":"2020-08-04T11:11:52.813327+02:00",
            "readable":"2020-08-04T11:11:52.867918+02:00",
            "fetchid":740
         },
         {
            "id":66,
            "pid":"None",
            "title":"None",
            "stand":"2020-08-04T11:04:28.049269+02:00",
            "filename":"20200804110554_None",
            "fileformat":"xlb",
            "processed":"2020-08-04T11:04:28.346942+02:00",
            "valid":"2020-08-04T11:04:28.052966+02:00",
            "readable":"2020-08-04T11:04:28.105237+02:00",
            "fetchid":740
         },
         {
            "id":65,
            "pid":"None",
            "title":"None",
            "stand":"2020-08-04T11:04:03.364790+02:00",
            "filename":"20200804110529_None",
            "fileformat":"xlb",
            "processed":"2020-08-04T11:04:03.667429+02:00",
            "valid":"2020-08-04T11:04:03.371583+02:00",
            "readable":"2020-08-04T11:04:03.428413+02:00",
            "fetchid":740
         },
         {
            "id":64,
            "pid":"None",
            "title":"None",
            "stand":"2020-08-04T11:00:49.168056+02:00",
            "filename":"20200804110215_None",
            "fileformat":"xlb",
            "processed":"2020-08-04T11:00:49.443963+02:00",
            "valid":"2020-08-04T11:00:49.175522+02:00",
            "readable":"2020-08-04T11:00:49.229073+02:00",
            "fetchid":740
         },
         {
            "id":62,
            "pid":"None",
            "title":"None",
            "stand":"2020-07-31T12:20:42.140621+02:00",
            "filename":"20200731122435_None",
            "fileformat":"xlsx",
            "processed":"2020-07-31T12:20:42.740335+02:00",
            "valid":"2020-07-31T12:20:42.147128+02:00",
            "readable":"2020-07-31T12:20:42.165955+02:00",
            "fetchid":740
         },
         {
            "id":48,
            "pid":"None",
            "title":"None",
            "stand":"2020-07-30T13:14:38.574587+02:00",
            "filename":"20200730131831_None",
            "fileformat":"xlsx",
            "processed":"2020-07-30T13:14:53.562254+02:00",
            "valid":"2020-07-30T13:14:38.774570+02:00",
            "readable":"2020-07-30T13:14:38.888142+02:00",
            "fetchid":740
         }
      ]
   },
   "mode":"table"
}
```

I tried various ways, and I can not use the ajax function that Datatables offers as the columns need to remain dynamic.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: You're adding columns as `data.data.columns` - but what *is* `data.data.columns` - check with `console.log(data.data.columns)`, oh, it's `undefined` - why might that be?  `data == { "code":1, "data":{ "colums"....`  ... `columns: data.data.colums` and it works fine.  Terrible typo.

Comment: You have to show your HTML table. I've got this error, and there was an HTML syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clearly getting you as much of the details on how you display that content with html has not been given. Besides, I do not have enough reputations to make me ask your more on the details regarding the display of the data captured from the server via ajax, but I still think that the data if echoed in html it is giving you the results you need and the alert or popup with that Error "Uncaught error: t is undefined":

hence, I suggest you review the following discussions:

-

1. [datatables-typeerror-i-is-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767889/datatables-typeerror-i-is-undefined)
2. [how-can-i-fix-typeerror-i-is-undefined](http://%20https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46682/how-can-i-fix-typeerror-i-is-undefined)

All the best.

Comment: The HTML has a simple div field which is used to output the table, within it I create a table element with an id (as shown in the code-snipped).

Comment: Okay, fine.  Then let me also research more on how to help you solve that issue.

Comment: I have noted that in that case of yours, you have only appended the table with json data but no row and columns demarcations. Hence, May you consider appending the rows and columns within the table.i.e. append <tr> and <td> tags.

Comment: *"you have only appended the table with json data but no row and columns demarcations"* - rows are defined with `data:` and columns defined with `columns:` in the `.DataTable({` code.   DataTables determines the columns from `<thead>` `columns:` is missing, but it's not missing - it's just `undefined` (really, datatables should check for this).