# Responsive datatable issue with colspan

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, responsive

I'm using a responsive datatable and that works fine, but the problem is with colspan.

When I use a td tag with colspan attribute, the page raise an error `datatables warning table id example requested unknown parameter 2` with this link https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4.

this is the snippet of code :

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" >Not in list</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use rowspan and colspan in tbody using datatable.js in codeigniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290693/how-to-use-rowspan-and-colspan-in-tbody-using-datatable-js-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

colspan and rowspan have not been used in the tbody of the table.

Read the document carefully it is colspan which is creating the issue.

Comment: but when the datatable is not responsive, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

DataTables **do not support colspan or rowspan in tbody**. But the limitation can be overcome through a workaround. For your case, it will be adding 3 cells with dispaly:none . The snippet is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" >Not in list</td>
    <td style="display: none;"></td>
    <td style="display: none;"></td>
    <td style="display: none;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked long time ago, but maybe my answer can help someone...

You just need to make it dynamically, see Below Code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        ajax: 'myData.json',   
        createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex){
           
            if(data[0] === 'Not in list'){
                
                // Add COLSPAN attribute
                $('td:eq(1)', row).attr('colspan', 3);
                $('td:eq(2)', row).css('display', 'none');
                $('td:eq(3)', row).css('display', 'none');
                
                // Update cell data
                this.api().cell($('td:eq(1)', row)).data(' ');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also you may find additional explanation [here](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-colspan-in-table-body-tbody/#colspan-and-rowspan)