# Datatables.js incorrect columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a datatables with datatables.js, but I keep encountering a problem, it keeps showing an error saying incorrect number of columns, this is in asp.net core NET 7.0, so I am working with a model for my data.

**DataTables warning: table id=employeeTable - Incorrect column count. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/18 please fix this it still is not working**

```
<table id="employeeTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- Empty header for the toggle button -->
            <th></th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Second Name</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var employee in Model)
        {
            <tr class="parent-row">
                <td><i class="fas fa-arrow-right expand-icon"></i></td>
                <td>@employee.FirstName</td>
                <td>@employee.SecondName</td>
                <td>@employee.JobTitle</td>
                <td>@employee.Salary</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="child-row rowhide">
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="child-details">
                        About me: @employee.AboutMe
                        <br />
                        ID: @employee.Id
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        let table = $('#employeeTable').DataTable({
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]
        });

        $('#employeeTable tbody').on('click', '.expand-icon', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr.parent-row');
            var row = table.row(tr);

            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            } else {
                row.child(tr.next('tr.child-row').html()).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        });
    });
```

I want the page to have parent and child rows that can expand if you click on the toggle arrow.

Comment: do you have any updates on this issue?

Comment: All sorted you are a legend !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue in my side as you can see the table is loaded like what you want but it just gave us an alert.

[image]

Inside the document it mentioned, we could see that

> Ensure colspan and rowspan are not used in the table body rows

[image]

That's the reason, so the easiest workaround for this scenario is setting the other 3  invisible like `<td style="display:none"></td>` and add a comment here with description that to avoid datatablejs warning. I'm also trying to find some other soltuion. But right now I only found [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34012324) which used display none as well. By the way, the `columnDefs` is not suitable for your [toggle action](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

[image]